# Filtering Google Analytics pages for Uppercase characters

Tags: google-analytics, regular-expression, regex

I'm trying to see if users have accessed URLs with uppercase characters.

I have gone into **`Behavior>Site Content>All`** Pages and am attempting to filter using Regex.

However, my syntax is not correct and it is saying I need `RE2` syntax.

can anyone help?

Comment: Can you share your regex that you've attempted, and also some example URLs that you are trying to filter out?